# ng-bootstrap popover increases page width

Tags: angular, typescript, popover, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a button at the right top corner of a page. I need to show a popover, but when I increase the width of its content, the page becomes larger and moves to the right, and the scroll bar appears at the bottom of the page. So I need to make the left side of the popover larger than the right side, with the triangle offset towards the right. But I don't know if it is posible...

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styles: [`
    div {
      display: flex;
    }
    button {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .my-custom-class {
      width: 400px;
      background: aliceblue;
      font-size: 125%;
    }
    .my-custom-class .arrow::after {
      border-top-color: aliceblue;
    }
  `]
})
export class HelloComponent  {}
```

hello.component.html

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbPopover="Nice class!"
      popoverClass="my-custom-class" placement="bottom">
      Popover
    </button>
</div>
```

I also provided a working example on stackblitz: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfzrrr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bottom-right` [placement](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api) to make sure that the right side of the popover is aligned with the right side of the button, and that the popover does not increase the page content width:

```
<button ... ngbPopover="Nice class!" placement="bottom-right">
  Popover
</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnww24) for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I suggest you to work with inspectElement and use different measuring units except px. 
For example % , vh & vw (both used for responsible windows)

Next at your css styling work with .my-custom-class

```
  .my-custom-class {
  width: 400px; //better change this to width:50% or 50 vw
  background: aliceblue;
  font-size: 125%;
  //also add these lines 
  left: 28px !important; //this is changeable to left:5% 
  position:absolute;
}
```